# codification of whammy.js fails

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, webrtc

I've been developing a mediastream application capturing video and audio using [mediastreamrecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) and [whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy).

In this process I have found a issue and I suspect it is related to the way [whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) render and store into a blob var.

I realiced about this because I was trying to encode audio (wav) and video (webm) into mp4 with `ffmpeg`.
For any reason I don't really know at all, some of the videos were encoded correctly but others were not. When It wasn't encoded correctly, the video was not fluent but the audio was.

I've been using this ffmpeg sentence:

```
'ffmpeg -i path/to/file.wav -i path/to/file.webm -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k path/to/file.mp4'
```

Then checking with ffprobe on a good conversion and a bad conversion into mp4 with the same camera I got what it comes:

For the good one:

```
ffprobe version N-77003-g64f7db5 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/devstarlight/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.101 / 57. 16.101
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 19.100 /  6. 19.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/devstarlight/Escritorio/178.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 5821 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 400x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 5841 kb/s, 16 fps, 16 tbr, 16384 tbn, 32 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

For the wrong conversion:

```
ffprobe version N-77003-g64f7db5 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/devstarlight/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.101 / 57. 16.101
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 19.100 /  6. 19.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/devstarlight/Escritorio/179.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 12815 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 400x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 13381 kb/s, 1000.24 fps, 1k tbr, 16k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Then I looked into the webm files directly and I realiced that there was no fps defined in the bad file:

The good record:

```
ffprobe version N-77003-g64f7db5 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/devstarlight/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.101 / 57. 16.101
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 19.100 /  6. 19.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/home/devstarlight/Escritorio/179.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : whammy
  Duration: 00:00:04.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1859 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 400x400, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

The bad record:

```
ffprobe version N-77003-g64f7db5 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/devstarlight/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/devstarlight/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavcodec     57. 16.101 / 57. 16.101
  libavformat    57. 19.100 / 57. 19.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 19.100 /  6. 19.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/home/devstarlight/Escritorio/178.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : whammy
  Duration: 00:00:04.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1461 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 400x400, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 16 fps, 16 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
```

`ffmpeg` output rate option (-r) is empty and rate is forced to 25 fps (because in fact in the `webm` it doesn't exist).

Is that issue registered at any point or someone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: i'm also willing to solve this. didnt find any clue. useful post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy/issues/70#issuecomment-890312941)

Just replase this code in whammy.js:

```
var webp = parseWebP(parseRIFF(atob(frame.image.slice(23))))
```

With this:

```
        var str = atob(frame.image.slice(23))
        
        // Process for WEBPVP8X encoding
        if(str.includes('WEBPVP8X')){
          // save 0-15
          // The length to be removed in the middle is 562 B, which is to remove 16-577
          // save 578-end
          var p1 = str.substr(0,15)
          var p2 = str.substr(577)
          str = p1 + p2
        }
        
        var webp = parseWebP(parseRIFF(str))
```